# OpenTelemetry JavaScript Lambda CloudWatch logs not grouping

Tags: open-telemetry

I've got a JS lambda (Node 14.x) that's sending OTel logs to a collector in a Lambda layer (v1-5-0:1). Right now, debug logging is enabled, but when I deploy the lambda, the CloudWatch logs are pretty printed and span multiple lines. Is there a way to group these lines into one CloudWatch log? Preferably just some JSON structure?

Here is what I see in the logs

[image]

and here is the OTel config:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

exporters:
  logging:
    loglevel: debug

  awsxray:
  otlp:
    endpoint: <my-endpoint>

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [awsxray, logging, otlp]
```

Comment: BTW: they are not a "logs", but they are"traces"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json log encoding:

```
...
service:
  telemetry:
    logs:
      encoding: json
...
```